# Auto Resize Text to Fit Form Input with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I'm looking for a method, using jQuery, to change the font size in a form input field so that no matter how much the user types, it is always visible and fits. In other words, to start with a font size of 13px and when the text reaches the width of the input field, the font size progressively gets smaller to accommodate.

I've found many methods of resizing the field itself, but not the text. Hopefully one of you who know jQuery better than I can help out.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at the fittext plugin. It might have some answers to this problem: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/vxsx/jquery.inputfit.js

Comment: I will take a look at that and let you know how it works. Thanks!